# How to use *ngFor with reference in another component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngfor

How would I go for referencing an Element in the dom which was created in a ngFor loop.

I want to get native element from component

this doesn't work

```
@Component({
    selector: "another-component",
    template: `
        <some-component #someComponent *ngFor="let someComponent of someComponents"
                [title]="someComponent.title"
        >
        </some-component>
    `
})
export class AnotherComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @input()
   someComponents: SomeComponent[];

   @ViewChildren("some-component")
   someComponentElems: QueryList<ElementRef>;

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.someComponentElems.forEach(elem => console.log(elem.nativeElement));
   }
}

@Component({
    selector: "some-component",
    template: `<span>{{title}}</span>`
})
export class AnotherComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @Input()
   title: string;
}
```

Comment: By using a second component and an Input into it seems the best solution.

Comment: @ViewChildren("some-component", { read: ElementRef })